# get "libcephfs.so:undefined reference to 'blablabla' " error during compiler. How to do solve this problem?

Tags: gcc, undefined, ld, ceph, cephfs

I have a cephfs and i'm writing a client code in c language using libcephfs.h library for it.

Note: installed libcephfs-dev and libcephfs2, but did not work on any version(12.2.12 or 12.2.4) I am using ubuntu 18.04.3.

> ```
> #include "/usr/include/cephfs/libcephfs.h"
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main (int argc, const char* argv[]){
>
>     struct ceph_mount_info *cmount;
>
>     const char id[] = "client.admin";
>
>     int err = ceph_create(&cmount, id);
>
>     printf("%d", err);
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

**$ g++ -o example example.c -lcephfs**

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcephfs.so: undefined reference to `AdminSocket::unregister_command(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcephfs.so: undefined reference to `ceph_clock_now()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcephfs.so: undefined reference to `AdminSocket::register_command(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, AdminSocketHook*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcephfs.so: undefined reference to `PerfCountersBuilder::add_u64_counter(int, char const*, char const*, char const*, int)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcephfs.so: undefined reference to `md_config_t::set_val(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, bool, std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcephfs.so: undefined reference to `CrushWrapper::get_full_location_ordered(int, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcephfs.so: undefined reference to `PerfCounters::tinc(int, utime_t, unsigned int)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcephfs.so: undefined reference to `md_config_t::parse_env()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcephfs.so: undefined reference to `md_config_t::parse_argv(std::vector<char const*, std::allocator<char const*> >&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcephfs.so: undefined reference to `ceph::Formatter::create(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcephfs.so: undefined reference to `PerfCounters::tinc(int, std::chrono::duration<unsigned long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >, unsigned int)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcephfs.so: undefined reference to `FSMap::parse_role(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, mds_role_t*, std::ostream&) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The error suggests you have a dependency of libcephfs.so missing, or a version mismatch between libcephfs.so and what it depends on. A basic things to try would be to reinstall the lib *and* its dependencies from scratch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It worked ! Before upgrading my ubuntu version(from 16.04 to 18.04), i have installed librados. Now, i reinstall librados and libcephfs. It worked successfully.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64

#include <cephfs/libcephfs.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]){

    struct ceph_mount_info *cmount;

    const char id[] = "client.admin";

    int err = ceph_create(&cmount, id);

    printf("%d", err);

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles for me on Ubuntu 18.04 with the GCC 7 compiler.
The command I used to compile is :

```
g++ -o example example.c -lcephfs
```

In fact, even your source compiles on my system with the added #defines that I have used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using gcc version 7 and ubuntu version 18.04.3. Is there a difference between ubuntu 18.04.3 and 18.04.2 or 18.04.1. Could this be the problem?